Questions about ranges::distance implementation
I'm reading ranges::distance source and don't get the idea that:

Why is the struct __distance_fn final?
What is the purpose of void operator&() const = delete (source)

I know that a final class has no derived classes, and the unary & is to get a pointer (or something alike) of an object. But I can't comprehend what they really do here with ranges::distance.
Same case for ranges::advance/prev/next, while other functors don't have such details, e.g. ranges::begin.

Why doesn't ranges::begin (and other functors) have final or deleted operator &?


Added the libstd++ tag - this is the specfic implementation in it.

A question should be self-contained and must not rely on links to make sense, you should paste the relevant code here. The pasted code will need to be edited to be minimal for your question, see [mre].

All those in question are called CPO(Customization Point Objects). They are normally implemented as function objects(Neibloids, because of Eric Neibler). Main property of them is fine control on overloading and preventing ADL. There's just no reason to drive from decltype of a CPO; that's why they don't have user accessible names(mind the leading double underscore in their names).

What is a niebloid?

@JeJo What usage/misuse cases do they enforce/prevent? Maybe that's what I'm really asking.

My question isn't about niebloid. I'm asking the final and operator & specifically. @Red.Wave If "There's no reason to derive from decltype of a CPO", why aren't other functors final? Same if "there is no reason to get a pointer of a CPO".

@DoZerg which other functors?

I'm speculating now, but isn't that due to the fact, that generally functions in std:: are supposed to be non-adressable, unless otherwise noted? What I'm not sure of is if those function objects count as functions. See 2.3 here and this post.

ranges::next is a so-called niebloid, unlike customization point objects (CPO), they are not function objects.
To mimic their characteristics and prevent them from being misused as objects, this commit in libstdc++ added final and deleted oeprator& to them so that it is not possible to derive from them and take their addresses.
On the other hand, ranges::begin is specified as CPO in the standard which is a function object that can be copied freely.
There is also a paper P3136: Retiring niebloids that turns niebloids into CPOs to remove their annoying non-object nature.

that turns niebloids into CPOs -- Do you mean "turns niebloids into function objects"?

"ranges::next ... are not function objects." That may explain deleted operator& (and final). But why did the commit modify ranges::begin while "ranges::begin is specified as CPO"? Does the Standard say CPO is NOT addressable?

@DoZerg Thats incorrect, so they revert for ranges::begin later.

@康桓瑋 So just to verify my understandings: In the current C++ terminology, CPO is non-final and addressable, while Niebloid is final and non-addressable. In the future, Nieblod may (or may not) merge to CPO, which means they may become non-final and addressable. Right?

@DoZerg CPO is a function object that can be default-constructed and copied. Niebloid is not guaranteed to be a function object so its object-ness cannot be relied upon, which includes taking addresses of it or deriving from it, and of course copying or default-constructing it.
